Await dispatch does not seem to be working (VueX)
I have functions createSwipe, fetchUserSwipes, and fetchSwipedUserSwipes. I call fetchUserSwipes and fetchSwipedUserSwipes inside createSwipe using these:
await dispatch('fetchSwipedUserSwipes', swipedUserId);
await dispatch('fetchUserSwipes', userId);

They don't seem to be called because the console logs I included in those functions are not printing in the console. These are the console logs:
//in fetchUserSwipes
console.log('Fetched User swipes:', data.userSwipes);

//in fetchSwipedUserSwipes
console.log('Fetched Swiped User swipes:', data.userSwipes);

Here is the rest of the code:
import { gql } from '@apollo/client/core';
import { apolloProvider } from '@/apollo-config'; 

const GET_TOTAL_SWIPES = gql`
    query {
        totalSwipes
    }
`;

const CREATE_SWIPE = gql`
    mutation($input: CreateSwipeInput!) {
        createSwipe(input: $input) {
            id
            userId
            swipedUserId
            likedBack
            createdAt
            updatedAt
        }
    }
`;

const GET_USER_SWIPES = gql`
  query GetUserSwipes($userId: ID!) {
    userSwipes(userId: $userId) {
      id
      userId
      swipedUserId
      likedBack
    }
  }
`;

const state = {
  totalSwipes: 0,
  userSwipes: {},
  swipedUserSwipes: {},  
  errorMessage: '',
};

const getters = {
  getTotalSwipes: state => state.totalSwipes,
  getUserSwipes: state => state.userSwipes,
  getSwipedUserSwipes: state => state.swipedUserSwipes,
  getSwipesCountErrorMessage: state => state.errorMessage,
  getCreateSwipeErrorMessage: state => state.errorMessage,
};

const actions = {
    async fetchTotalSwipes({ commit }) {
        try {
            const { data } = await apolloProvider.defaultClient.query({
                query: GET_TOTAL_SWIPES,
            });
            commit('SET_TOTAL_SWIPES', data.totalSwipes);
            console.log('Total Swipes:', data.totalSwipes);
        } catch (error) {
            commit('SET_ERROR_MESSAGE', error.message);
        }
    },
    async createSwipe({ commit, dispatch, getters }, { userId, swipedUserId }) {
      try {
        const { data } = await apolloProvider.defaultClient.mutate({
          mutation: CREATE_SWIPE,
          variables: { input: { userId, swipedUserId } },
        });
  
        const swipe = data.createSwipe;
  
        // Fetch swipes for the swiped user
        await dispatch('fetchSwipedUserSwipes', swipedUserId);
        await dispatch('fetchUserSwipes', userId);
  
        // Get the swiped user's swipes from the getter
        const swipedUserSwipes = getters.getSwipedUserSwipes[swipedUserId] || [];
        const matchingSwipe = swipedUserSwipes.find(swipe => swipe.userId === userId);
  
        if (matchingSwipe) {
          // Set likedBack to true for both users
          matchingSwipe.likedBack = true;
          swipe.likedBack = true;
  
          // Create matches for both users
          await dispatch('matches/createMatch', { userId, matchedUserId: swipedUserId }, { root: true });
          await dispatch('matches/createMatch', { userId: swipedUserId, matchedUserId: userId }, { root: true });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        commit('SET_ERROR_MESSAGE', error.message);
      }
    },
    async fetchSwipedUserSwipes({ commit }, userId) {
      try {
        const { data } = await apolloProvider.defaultClient.query({
          query: GET_USER_SWIPES,
          variables: { userId },
        });
        commit('SET_SWIPED_USER_SWIPES', { userId, swipes: data.userSwipes });
        console.log('Fetched Swiped User swipes:', data.userSwipes);
      } catch (error) {
        commit('SET_ERROR_MESSAGE', error.message);
      }
    },       
    async fetchUserSwipes({ commit }, userId) {
      try {
        const { data } = await apolloProvider.defaultClient.query({
          query: GET_USER_SWIPES,
          variables: { userId },
        });
  
        commit('SET_USER_SWIPES', { userId, swipes: data.userSwipes });
        console.log('Fetched User swipes:', data.userSwipes);
      } catch (error) {
        commit('SET_ERROR_MESSAGE', error.message);
      }
    },
};

const mutations = {
  SET_TOTAL_SWIPES(state, totalSwipes) {
      state.totalSwipes = totalSwipes;
  },
  SET_USER_SWIPES(state, { userId, swipes }) {
    state.userSwipes = {
      ...state.userSwipes,
      [userId]: swipes,
    };
  },
  SET_SWIPED_USER_SWIPES(state, { userId, swipes }) {
    state.swipedUserSwipes = {
      ...state.swipedUserSwipes,
      [userId]: swipes,
    };
  },
  SET_ERROR_MESSAGE(state, message) {
      state.errorMessage = message;
  },
};

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,
};


Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

no errors in console?  I think with Vuex it should be this.dispatch() to call actions within the same store module

nope. no errors are being printed. i'll try this.dispatch() and will report back if it worked. thank you for the response!

Unfortunately, it didn't work. Returned these errors:
[vuex] unknown action type: fetchSwipedUserSwipes [vuex] unknown action type: fetchUserSwipes 

The actions can be called using dispatch when invoking actions of the same store, I think the issue is of try-catch usage, move your console log outside of try-catch and see that if the actions are called or not.

I see console.log at the end of the optimistic try block. What if its throws before reaching the console.log?
... in comment to your question you say unknown action type - tipicly with namespaced: true you shoud call actions outside of the module with a namespace like this: dispatch('my-module/my-action') where my-module is the name of the store, but thats probably the case of how you import and use this exports... Can you provide this usecase?
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,
};

